# Efficient way to transfer files to 1000s of servers

Tags: file-transfer, scp

I was recently asked this question in an interview. Lets suppose I have 2000 servers. I want to transfer a 5GB file to all these servers from a centralized server. Come up with an efficient algorithm.

My response:
I will use perl/python to scp the file over from the centralized server to the first server.
In parallel, I will also start sending files to other servers. I feel doing one by one is very inefficient hence doing in parallel would speed up.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Efficient is not necessarily CPU-efficient. Doing it in parallel is as bandwidth inefficient as doing it serially.

Comment: All I know is that the interviewer wanted to hear something more advanced, than sending them parallelly...

Comment: Should we assume all machines are linked to a central switch/router, and have equal bandwidth?

Comment: Parallelism only improves performance if you have multiple cores or blocking operations. If the bandwidth is a bottleneck, because it's very small, maybe parallelism improves performance...?

Comment: How about look at this link? http://moo.nac.uci.edu/~hjm/HOWTO_move_data.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, you would use some sort of script, since you don't want to do that manually. 
But instead of sending all the files from one server to all the others, you would start sending the file to k Servers. As soon as these k Servers received the file (let's say at time t), they can start distributing the file too, so after approx. time 2*t already k^2 servers have the file instead of 2*k in the original solution. After time 3*t already k^3 Servers have got the file... You continue with that algorithm until every server has got it's file.

To make the whole process yet a bit faster, you could also divide the file in chunks, so that a server can start redistributing it before it has received the whole file (you will end up with something like torrent)

Comment: +1. It should be noted, however, that the speedup you can achieve by doing this (or any other parallelization trick) depends on the network topology (the manner in which the servers are connected to each other). By the way, a common term for the approach you are describing is _scatter_.

Comment: Probably not what the interviewer wanted to hear, but you could also use multicast. Multicast is not yet widespread to this day, but some providers use it in their own network to provide IPTV to their customers.

Answer (score 9):

Definitely "torrent" is the best and proven strategy for load-balancing in this scenario. But I think when an interview asks such hypothetical question to me, she is probably also looking for your assumptions and expecting counter questions.

1. upload / download capacity of servers.
2. network localization, i.e how many hops are different machines.
3. can the file be archived and send
4. how to verify integrity (md5 hash)

Now my scheme remains the same "torrent" thanks to @Misch. But if all servers are on same n/w and are of same capacity then;

1. Divide file into 2000 parts, each server gets 5GB/2000 ~ 2.5 MB (file segment) to host and central acts as a beacon server to tell other server where the files are.
2. Each server would download these chunks in **random order** from other server, if we download sequentially then it causes bottleneck on one machine.

Depending on machine we can have max active upload/download threads, each thread up/down separate file segment. when a server is serving maximum hosts, it can reject file download request. Requesting host would simple pickup another random segment to download.

1. We can use some checksum for individual file segment & all files combined, to verify file integrity.

This ensures that all servers are upload/downloading close to their up/down stream bandwidth. But obviously in a real world I can have a secured torrent and just use that instead.

Comment: After reading @Mansoor Siddiqui's answer I think dividing into n (=2000) servers wouldn't be good, instead file should be divided into infinitesimally small chunks.

Comment: Best answer if you ask me!

Answer (score 3):

If you split the file into tiny chunks, then each server can begin transferring the chunks that it has received before the entire file has even been downloaded.  This is basically the algorithm that bittorrent uses, and is MUCH (i.e. asymptotically) faster than having the servers send the file only after it has received the whole thing.

In fact, with an infinitesimally small chunk size (i.e. the purely theoretical case), the time it takes to distribute a file of size `m` to `n` servers doesn't even depend on the value of `n` -- only on the size of the file being distributed (i.e. O(`m`)).  Of course, in the practical case there are some overheads/details to consider (which [d1val](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11344956/477451) summarized nicely) which make it take slightly longer in practice.

Conversely, if you have each server upload the file to another server only after it has received the whole file, then the running time is O(`m` log(`n`)) -- which is asymptotically larger than the bittorrent approach.

Also, just to add, *usually* when an interview asks this kind of question, he/she is asking about the algorithm, not so much the implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

I was asked a similar kind of question where in the torrent way of doing things was not accepted. 
The question was "If microsoft has to push a software update to 2000 servers it has across US then how would it do it"- So these servers are not capable of doing torrent based file transfer.

My Answer was: 
From the main server with a list of 2000 nodes have a batching process, the capacity of the batch will be determined by the network speed you have across to these nodes.

1. So First select a sample of 100 nodes and do a speedtest across these node. A speed test will give an indication of what is the median speed which is available across these 100 nodes and may be that acts as a sample to the entire network.
2. So now you have a value of X Mbps is the speed at which you can do a transfer across to these nodes.
3. Look at the capcity of your own outgoing data speed. So if the central server has a capacity of YGbps as its upload speed

then the batching size = Your Upload Capacity (Y)/ X(speed found by speedtest).

According to this batching size you move ahead in transferring parallelly to 2000 server in batches.

Any Inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could put the file on NFS server and have your hosts mount that NFS partition.